# I can't view this HTML excersise

Tags: html, css

i'm pretty new into this topic, i'm actually doing the HTML & CSS course at Codecademy. i just found and solve a little excersise about HTML but i can't actually view it properly in the browser, can any of you give me any light about what did i miss? thak you.

```css
b {
  font-family: Verdana;
  }
h1 {
  color: #333;
     font-size: 20px;  
  }
h2 {
 color: #666;
 font-size: 16px;
 
}
p, li {
 color: #000;
 font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!CODETYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="es-ES">
<!-- Practica HTML 15/02/2017 -->
  <link hrel="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset= "utf-8">
  <title> Recetas de cocina/Patatas fritas</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Patatas fritas</h1>
    <p>Receta de patatas fritas caseras.</p>
  <img src="http://www.abrirllave.com/html/images/patatas-fritas.jpg" alt="Patatas fritas perfectas" width="300" height="225"/>
  <h2>Ingredientes</h2>
    <ul>
     <li>3 &oacute 4 patatas (300gr.)</li>
  <li>4 dientes de ajo</li>
  <li>Aceite de oliva</li>
  <li>Sal</li>
 </ul>
  <h2>Elaboraci&oacute;n (Pasos)</h2>
    <ol>
  <li>Calentar aceite en una sart&eacute;n.</li>
  <li>A&ntilde;adir las patatas cortadas, sal y el ajo.</li>
  <li>Fre&iacute;r al gusto.</li>
  <li>Servir en plato.</li>
 </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

right, i just put it in the code snippet and it worked, may be my problem in my folder locations? if any of you could tell me good exercises i will be very gateful, i need to practice what i just learned.

Comment: <link hrel="style.css" - This should read <link href="style.css", this may be why your style doesn't load. What doesn't work on your local?

Comment: And doctype, not codetype

Comment: thank you for that @Tristan Hudson, I did fail with that one about the href. it may be that I dont know clearly where and how to run it, i'm googling it atm.

Comment: I solved it dude. thank you very very much to take the time to check this, keep it up!

Comment: Here's some further reading for the future just in case you need it: https://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Answer (score 0):

Take out `<!CODETYPE html>`
Use `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: buh dude that one was a real fail for me hehe, thank you very much. for what i see i really need practice and evaluation

Comment: thank you bro, now it works. thank you to take the time to check this, was very educational for me hehe. keep doing it like that.-

Comment: Good luck with everything